# Cloning SSD w/ OS onto SSD w/ data already on it. Partition?

Tags: disk-cloning, m.2

I need to upgrade my storage in my computer but only have one slot for my M.2, so cloning to my new M.2 through my computer is not possible. My idea for a solution is to clone my current M.2 onto my external 2TB drive and then clone that onto the new M.2 after I put it in. I want the clone to keep my OS.

The problem is that my 2TB external drive has about 400GB of files on it. How can I do the cloning without messing up the current data on the external? I know there's something like partitioning drives. I just don't know how to do it and I am failing at searching for the answer online.

Comment: You can use any (reliable) tool that clones drive > file and then do the reverse, as usual and as always has been with this sort of software tools and procedure. That said said perhaps better to do your backups and install from scratch to the new drive. Guaranteed  some or better results, typically less time and way less points of possible failure.

Comment: They sell USB NVMe M.2 enclosures that would allow you to clone your drive. It might take awhile. But cloning is typically a time consuming process anyway